# Explode string from database separated with comma

Tags: php, explode

I have in database row `services` where have data `Live, Text, Video` separated with commas

This data is stored from checkboxes with implode function.

Now I need to explode `Live` `Text` `Video` individually and with `if` conditions to show different HTML code

```
<div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Live service"><i class="fas fa-video"></i></div>
<div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Text service"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></div>
<div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Video service"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></div>
```

I know what to do with `if` but can't get it individually.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT `id`, `title`, `text`, `main_image`, `tags`, `services` FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8');

// Retrieve query results
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $text, $naslovna, $tags, $services);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // Add result to accounts array
    $news[] = ['id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'text' => $text, 'naslovna' => $naslovna, 'tags' => $tags, 'services' => $services];
    $services = explode(", ", $services);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selected everything with one query

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT `id`, `title`, `text`, `main_image`, `tags`, `services` FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8');

// Retrieve query results
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $text, $naslovna, $tags, $services);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // Add result to accounts array
    $news[] = ['id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'text' => $text, 'naslovna' => $naslovna, 'tags' => $tags, 'services' => $services];
}
```

And printed with `if` statement

```
<?php
$service = explode(", ", $new['services']);
if (in_array('Live', $service)) { ?>
   <div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Live servis"><i class="fas fa-tower-broadcast"></i></div>
<?php }
if (in_array('Text', $service)) {  ?>
   <div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Tekst servis"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></div>
<?php }
if (in_array('Video', $service)) {  ?>
<div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Video servis"><i class="fas fa-video"></i></div>
<?php }
if (in_array('Photo', $service)) {  ?>
   <div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Foto servis"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is working but, it is safe?

Comment: "Safe" in what sense? Safety is a sliding scale, not a yes/no. What are you concerned about?

Comment: I mean it is safe for use. I am concerned about the secure code. No attack can be carried out like SQL injection

Comment: SQL injection is impossible in this case because the SQL statement is hard-coded, and not dependent on external, user-supplied data. As long as there is no *other* means for the contents of the DB to be altered, this code is safe.

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing anything returned by the call to `$stmt->fetch()`. You need to do something like this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $servis = $row['services'];
    $services = explode(', ', $servis);
}
```

Once you have created the array of services, you can output your HTMLseveral ways, including an `if()` or `switch()`. But it would probably be more efficient this way, in which the title and class are derived from the service:

```
<?php
foreach($services as $svc) {
    $title = ['Live' => 'Live', 'Text' => 'Text', 'Video' => 'Photo'][$svc];
    $c = ['Live' => 'fa-video', 'Text' => 'fa-align-justify', 'Video' => 'fa-camera'][$svc];
?>
    <div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="<?= $title ?> service">
      <i class="fas <?= $c ?>"></i>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is the `switch()` version:

```php
<?php
foreach($services as $svc) {
    switch ($svc) {
        case 'Live':
?>
<div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Live service"><i class="fas fa-video"></i></div>
<?php
        break;
        case 'Text':
?>
<div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Text service"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></div>
<?php
        break;
        case 'Video':
?>
<div class="icon-sm bg-black-soft bg-blur text-white rounded-circle" title="Photo service"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></div>
<?php
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I know how to do it in HTML with an if statement, but I can't explode with PHP code. I think something is wrong with my code.

Comment: @MarkoStevanović See my updated answer.

Comment: When I try `print_r($services);` show me Array ( [0] => )

Comment: @MarkoStevanović What does `print_r($row)'` show?

Comment: Show me `1` I print it inside in the `while` loop

Comment: Ok, I see you're using `bind_result()` to store the results, which means you don't need to assign the results to `$row`. What does the SQL statement return when you execute it directly, e.g. in MySQL or phpMyAdmin? Are you sure there are results in your DB?

Comment: To execute `SELECT services FROM news` ? Show me services with data `Live, Text, Video`

Comment: If you can check, update the query @kmoser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246557/discussion-between-marko-stevanovic-and-kmoser).